For purposes of loop progress, does "atomic operation" include fences?
C++ has a "forward progress" requirement for loops:

(6.9.2.3p1) The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one
of the following:

terminate,
invoke the function std​::​this_thread​::​yield ([thread.thread.this]),
make a call to a library I/O function,
perform an access through a volatile glvalue,
perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation, or
continue execution of a trivial infinite loop ([stmt.iter.general]). [Added in C++23]


So an infinite loop that doesn't do any of these things (and doesn't meet the definition of a "trivial infinite loop") causes undefined behavior.
For purposes of item 5, is a fence considered to be an "synchronization operation or atomic operation"?  If we have a non-trivial infinite loop whose body contains an atomic_signal_fence() or atomic_thread_fence() but no other side effects, does this cause undefined behavior?
I don't think there's an explicit definition or exhaustive list of "atomic operations" anywhere in the standard.  atomics.fences describes them as "synchronization primitives" instead, and arguably it doesn't make sense for fences to count as observable effects here, because they don't actually have any observable effects of their own.  On the other hand, atomics.order p4, in another context, speaks of a total order on "all memory_order​::​seq_cst operations, including fences", suggesting that they are considered "operations".
Bonus question: does it make a difference if the fence has memory_order_relaxed ordering, which is explicitly defined as having no effect?
gcc and clang appear to differ here.  Given code like
bool b = true;
while (b) {
   std::atomic_signal_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

clang will delete the entire loop, and indeed emit no code at all for the function, which is its typical behavior when a function unconditionally causes UB if called.  Try on godbolt.
On the other hand, gcc will emit an infinite empty loop, even though it will happily delete such loops without a fence.
More elaborate example on godbolt.
The same thing happens for other memory orders and for atomic_thread_fence (in the latter case, gcc emits an infinite loop with a barrier instruction.)

[intro.races]#3 "...The library defines a number of atomic operations ([atomics]]) and operations on mutexes ..."

@RichardCritten: Indeed, but it doesn't actually say what they are.  Unless the implication is that it includes everything discussed in section [atomics]?

I think that is what is meant - the whole section 33.5 Atomic operations

I would think that any expression that interacts with a synchronization primitive is considered a synchronization operation

[intro.races]: "A synchronization operation without an associated memory location is a fence […] . In addition, there are relaxed atomic operations, which are not synchronization operations"

I am pretty sure Clang is wrong here, at least if the fence doesn't have relaxed memory ordering.
Whether or not an fences are atomic operations isn't even relevant.
According to [intro.races]/3 (non-relaxed) fences are at least synchronization operations and these are listed together with atomic operations in the same item in your quote. The explicit inclusion of atomic operations in the list is, I think, only to include relaxed and RMW operations on atomic objects.
The same clause excludes relaxed atomic operations from being synchronization operations. It also doesn't list relaxed fences as synchronization operations. So unfortunately, this can't resolve the question about them specifically.
That aside, there are open WG21 issues regarding the definition of "atomic operations": LWG 2506, CWG 2297, editorial issue.

Okay, I reported it: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/96702  It looks like clang has some related bugs involving operations that are no-ops but must count as forward progress, including loads of non-escaped local atomics, as well as printf("").

@NateEldredge The optimization itself, even without forward-progress, is also wrong, because it can cause two functions to get the same address, which shouldn't happen. I am surprised that hasn't been fixed yet since I think this has been a known issue for a while now.
